# HTML modal in asp.net mvc5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-5

Alright, so the deal is I am loading a modal with javascript but it's not very pretty and I would like to make it better looking this is how it looks right now.
[image]

And this is how the modal is being made with javascript.

```
function OpenDialog() {
    ClearDialog();
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
}

function OpenDialog2(id, projectId, startDate, endDate, pct) {
    ClearDialog();
    $('#projectList').val(projectId);
    $('#startDate').val(startDate);
    $('#endDate').val(endDate);
    $('#pct').val(pct);
    $('#sId').text(id);
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
}

function ClearDialog() {
    $('#projectList').val('');
    $('#startDate').val('');
    $('#endDate').val('');
    $('#pct').val('');
    $('#sId').text('');
}

$(function () {

    var comment = $("#tbComment"),
        locstring = '?consultantid=@(Request.QueryString["consultantid"])',
        allFields = $([]).add(comment),
        tips = $("#validateTips");

    function validate() {
        var pct = $('#pct').val();
        if (pct !== "" && (pct > 100 || pct < 0))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    function reloadTable() {
        if (navigator.appName === "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
            //alert('suck..');
            window.location.reload();
        } else {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@(Url.Action("ConsulantTimes"))',
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#dialog').dialog('close');
                    $('#ConsultantTimes').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    $("#dialog").dialog({
        bigframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 220,
        width: 305,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Spara': function () {

                if (!validate()) {
                    alert('Procent måste vara mellan 0-100');
                    return false;
                }

                locstring = "@(Url.Action("Index"))/Update/?";

                locstring += '&projectId=' + $('#projectList').val();
                locstring += '&startDate=' + $('#startDate').val();
                locstring += '&endDate=' + $('#endDate').val();
                locstring += '&pct=' + $('#pct').val();

                var sid = $('#sId').text();
                if (sid !== "") {
                    locstring += '&id=' + sid;
                    //locstring = "/Delete/" + sid;
                }
                //window.location = locstring;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: locstring,
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (data) {
                        //alert(locstring);
                        $('#dialog').dialog('close');
                        reloadTable();
                    }
                });

                return true;
            },
            'Avbryt': function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            'Ta bort': function () {
                var sid = $('#sId').text();
                if (sid !== "") {
                    locstring = "@(Url.Action("Index"))/Delete/" + sid;
                    //locstring += '&delete=true&id=' + sid;

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: locstring,
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#dialog').dialog('close');
                            reloadTable();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        },
        close: function () {
            allFields.val('').removeClass('ui-state-error');
        }
    });
```

How ever I wanted to make a new design for the modal that is not being generated with javascript and i came up with this. And it looks a lot better in my opinion.
[image]

And here is the HTML for that.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="basic" tabindex="-1" role="basic" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Projekt:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Start Datum:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Slut Daturm:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Tid (%)</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Spara</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ta bort</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">stäng</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I want that new modal to act like my new modal. But I have no clue how change it so my new modal will get the same values like the one that is being generated with javascript code.

**As in how will I get the drop down on my new modal etc?**

Comment: _And here is the HTML for that_. Where it is? I think you forgot to attach one?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I sure did, sorry for that.. my post been updated.

Comment: can you please show code as in how you used to get your previous `modal`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Just this                                         <a href="javascript:OpenDialog()" class="btn btn-primary">Lägg till ny</a>

Comment: Something like **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/93h3zo8q/)**

Comment: It's more to it than that. The I get from the database and only user who belong to that project should be available to choose it so hard coding in all those values would give all projects to every user. @gurup

Comment: That you can easily check in Razor view! You can add a condition for user and then display your view accordingly!